# Problem getting one of my fragments from SupportFragmentManager

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, fragmentmanager

I have this method in my MainActivity:

```
private fun ObtenerFragmentos() {

 var event1:Event_1? =null
 var event2:Event_2? =null
 var event3: Event_3? =null

     for(fragment: Fragment in supportFragmentManager.fragments){

         if (fragment is Event_1) event1 = fragment
         if(fragment is Event_2) event2 = fragment
         if(fragment is Event_3) event3 = fragment

     }

    }
```

The problems is that event3 its always null and supportFragmentManager.fragments.size always get 2 fragments but when I run the apk I can see and interact with the three fragments.

[image]

My classes and xml:

**activity_main3.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme1" >

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/mViewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_event"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorblanco"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorblanco" />
    </androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3)

        viewpageradapter = ViewPageAdapter(supportFragmentManager)
        mViewPager.adapter = viewpageradapter  
        tab_layout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager)
        tab_layout.getTabAt(0)!!.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_datos_generales)
        tab_layout.getTabAt(1)!!.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_repeat)
        tab_layout.getTabAt(2)!!.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_relaciones)
```

}

This is the ViewPageAdapter class:

```
class ViewPageAdapter(fm: androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager) : androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter(fm) {

    override fun getItem(position: Int): androidx.fragment.app.Fragment {
        var fragment: androidx.fragment.app.Fragment? = null
        when (position) {
            0 -> fragment = Event_1()
            1 -> fragment = Event_2()
            2 -> fragment = Event_3()
        }
        return fragment!!
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return 3
    }

    override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence? {
        var title: String? = null
        if (position == 0) {
            title = "Datos Generales"
        } else if (position == 1) {
            title = "Repeticiones"
        } else if (position == 2) {
            title = "Relaciones"
        }
        return title
    }
}
```

And the code of the three fragments are:

**Event_1:**

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        val viewo: View? = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_datos_generales, container, false)


        return viewo
    }
```

**Event_2:**

```
 override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val view: View? = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_repeticiones, container, false)
        return view
    }
```

**Event_3:**

```
 override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val view: View? = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_relaciones, container, false)
        return view
    }
```

Someone help me please!! Sorry for my English

Comment: Are you sure you have used the correct `androidx.fragment.app.Fragment` everywhere?

Comment: @sanjeev yes,in everywhere

Comment: Maybe trying to retrieve the fragments from the fragment manager isn't the best way to do this. Note that you're creating a new instance of each fragment on a call to getItem() - you could potentially store instances of each and then return the pre-created instance from here. That way you could access each fragment from the activity (through the adapter). Incidentally, where are you calling the `ObtenerFragmentos()` function from - is the result the same when called whilst viewing tab 3 for instance?

Comment: @ChrisShaw Thanks,you can show me a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the fragments static within the adapter, and then access them directly from the main activity without trying to extract them from the fragment manager.

As an example, change the top of the adapter as below.

```
class ViewPageAdapter(fm: androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager) : androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter(fm) {

  public var event1 = Event_1()
  public var event2 = Event_2()
  public var event3 = Event_3()

  override fun getItem(position: Int): androidx.fragment.app.Fragment? {
      return when (position) {
          0 -> event1
          1 -> event2
          2 -> event3
          else -> null
      }
  }
...
```

From the main activity you can then just use (e.g.)

```
viewpageradapter.event1
```